# Get data from array of object in Angular

Tags: angular, loops

I have an array of objects in my angular app and I am trying to read data in objects with "for loop" and I got nothing in the console. Here are the model and other details how I created the array object.

> file_info.model.ts

```
import { MSGraphService } from './../ms-graph.service';
export interface file_info {
  ms_graph: MSGraphService;
  file: any;
  sessionUrl: string;
}
```

> upload.component.ts

```
import { file_info } from 'src/app/models/file_info.model';
...
export class UploadFileComponent implements OnInit {
  files: File[];
  fileInfo: file_info[] = [];
...
async uploadFile(files: File[]) {
    for (const file of files) {
    .....
      this.ms_graph
        .get_upload_session(fileType, fileName, this.itemId)
        .subscribe(
          async (response: MSCreateUploadSession) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            // this.progressText = "Session created.";
            this.sessionUploadURL = response.uploadUrl;

            let uploadData = {
              ms_graph: this.ms_graph,
              file: file,
              sessionUrl: this.sessionUploadURL,
            };

            this.fileInfo.push(uploadData);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.error(
              'Error get_upload_session() \n' + JSON.stringify(error)
            );
            throw error;
          }
        );
    }
    this.uploadMultipleFiles(this.fileInfo);
  }
```

Now I trying to read data from **"this.fileInfo"**

```
  uploadMultipleFiles(files: file_info[]) {
    console.log(files);
    // for(let fileInfo of files) {
    //   console.log(fileInfo);
    // }

    // files.forEach(element => {
    //   console.log(element.file);
    // });

    for(var i=0; i<=files.length; i++) {
      console.log(files[i].file);
    }
  }
```

I tried several loop methods to extract the data from **fileInfo** object and nothing returned in the console.
when I console the **files**, it returns an array in the console.
Can anyone tell me how to get the **uploadData** variable data from **fileInfo** array iteration?

Comment: console.log(files[i]) What is output?

Comment: console.log(file[i]) return undefine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because

```js
this.uploadMultipleFiles(this.fileInfo);
```

is called before

```js
this.fileInfo.push(uploadData);
```

Due to being called in your subscription method.

---

**Solution**

You have to wait for all of your observables to fill the fileInfo array before using your upload method :)

You can wait for multiple observables to complete with [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin)

Comment: Thanks in advance and forkJoin is a good solution for this. But when I call the upload method as same as placed in my code it returns "[]" with data I pushed into fileInfo. When I selected 2 files it return an array like the below in the console. [] = 0: {ms_graph: xxxxxxx, file: File, sessionUrl: 'https://xxxxxx} 1:  {ms_graph: xxxxxxx, file: File, sessionUrl: 'https://xxxxxx}. Why is that not showing when I Iterate the array. If I am doing wrong how?

Comment: I believed you said `console.log(files[i])` returned undefined ?

Comment: So this means the array you passed to the function is empty when you call `uploadMultipleFiles`.  
For the same reason I explained :). 
Yes you will have an array, because you declared it like this `fileInfo: file_info[] = []`
But it will be empty because your obsevable isn't completed yet when calling `uploadMultipleFiles`

Comment: Yes, you are correct and I am into forkJoin. Sorry for asking below. I am new to angular and RxJS. If I use forkJoin option where/how to add it?

Comment: @MD40 you would fill an array of observables, like `observablesArray.push(this.ms_graph    .get_upload_session(fileType, fileName, this.itemId))`
Once you have them in an array, subscribe to the forkJoin of this array. In that subscribe, fill your fileInfo array. When fileInfo array is completely filled, call uploadMultipleFiles

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Anyway when subscribing to the array response must be MSCreateUploaSession type, otherwise it can not display the sessionUrl from element of the response array, but it is not accepted from subscription.     forkJoin(this.observableAnyArray).subscribe((response : MSCreateUploadSession) => { for(let i; i <=response.length; i++) {console.log(response);} }); Can I do this like above?

Comment: This really solved my issue and completed the tasks. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below, You need to call the function inside the subscribe section.

```
import { file_info } from 'src/app/models/file_info.model';
...
export class UploadFileComponent implements OnInit {
  files: File[];
  fileInfo: file_info[] = [];
...
async uploadFile(files: File[]) {
    for (const file of files) {
    .....
      this.ms_graph
        .get_upload_session(fileType, fileName, this.itemId)
        .subscribe(
          async (response: MSCreateUploadSession) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            // this.progressText = "Session created.";
            this.sessionUploadURL = response.uploadUrl;

            let uploadData = {
              ms_graph: this.ms_graph,
              file: file,
              sessionUrl: this.sessionUploadURL,
            };

            this.fileInfo.push(uploadData);
            // Call from here
            this.uploadMultipleFiles(this.fileInfo);

          },
          (error) => {
            console.error(
              'Error get_upload_session() \n' + JSON.stringify(error)
            );
            throw error;
          }
        );
    }
    // Here is the problem
    //this.uploadMultipleFiles(this.fileInfo);
  }
```